# Fetch/Read iframe URL in cross domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe with external src, the iframe page contain HTML form, when submits the form  parameters/attributes shows in URL using GET method.

BUT these parameter/querystring is not updating in my iframe src.

This is the page:
http://kff.org/interactive/subsidy-calculator

When submits the above form, the URL becomes:
http://kff.org/interactive/subsidy-calculator/#state=&zip=&income-type=dollars&income=23123&employer-coverage=0&people=1&alternate-plan-family=individual&adult-count=1&adults[0][age]=21&adults[0][tobacco]=0&child-count=0&child-tobacco=0

But when I pass the url to iframe in my page, it remains same after submitting the form :(

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: Imagine a terrible bank that sent a user to `bank.com/logon?user=bob&password=pencil` ... Browsers explicitly prevent you from accessing query data from a page on another domain in a frame.

Comment: But this site is not preventing you luckily, you can paste the url I share and you will find the fill form :)

Comment: *You* can see it, Javascript (via frame.src) cannot

Comment: (frame.src) shows old value not latest value.

Comment: Even bellow function didn't update the iframe src with query string:                             document.getElementById('FormID').contentWindow.location.reload(true);

Comment: Yes, you cannot read the querystring (the stuff after the ?) from an IFRAME that is pointing to another domain: http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy